# Image cut in half during Heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, deployment

Any idea why my image would be cut in half during a deploy to heroku?

Here is my simple image_tag

_header.html.haml

```
= image_tag 'some_image.png'
```

The image is located within app/assets/images. Any idea on how I could possibly debug this? I'm not so familiar with images. All the other images seem to work fine.